# How to search with cypher 2.0 case insensitive?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to search with cypher 2.0 / Neo4j 2.1.7 case insensitive on a indexed field?

- regex does not use index `WHERE a.X =~ ('(?i)' + b.Y) ...`
- using lower() does not use index `WHERE lower(a.X) = lower(b.Y) ...`
- adding a extra field with lower case property value for indexing is ugly

Not using the index will result in more them 2 mio DB Hits.

Comment: Have you tried lucene full-text indexes?  I've never tried using `PROFILE` with one of them so I'm not 100% sure they will reduce dbhits, but it's worth looking into.  http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-create-advanced.html

Comment: No, i'm only using the new schema indexes. Looks like the legacy indexes could only be set via the Java API, i'm using cypher only via REST API :(

Comment: No, you can create legacy lucene indexes via configuration, outside of java (http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-configurable-auto-indexes.html#rest-api-create-an-auto-index-for-nodes-with-specific-configuration)  and the `START` clause in cypher can exploit them.

Comment: Using lucene indexes with cypher:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360489/passing-a-lucene-query-to-neo4j-rest-api-using-cypher-2-0

Comment: What I can't answer for you is whether exploitation of these indexes will reduce dbhits, but I think they will.

Comment: Yep agreed with @FrobberOfBits use the manual indexes via REST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fulltext search using legacy indexes with Neo4j 2.x which is also case-insensitive check my blog post:

http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/