# Neo4j schema indexes for fuzzy search

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, fuzzy-search

Right now I'm thinking on possibility to create fuzzy search in my application over my Neo4j database.

The main criteria are: fuzzy search and performance.

What is the best way to achive these goals with a last version of Neo4j community edition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fuzzy search is a tricky thing. Even in plain lucene (where you can do fuzzy search with [lucene query strings](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy%20Searches)) it is not recommended because it is quite expensive.

You can use that query syntax in Neo4j too when you indexed your data with a [manual index](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing.html).

The solution that most suggest is to rather go with auto-suggestion, i.e. match on the first few characters, present the options in the auto-complete box and then search by using the user selected strings.

Comment: can I use match on regular expressions, for example (WHERE n.name =~ 'Tob.*') together with new Schema Indexes(not legacy indexes on Lucene) Will this work with regular expressions matching ?

Comment: Also, what do you think about the following approach for fuzzy search implementation https://github.com/sksamuel/elasticsearch-river-neo4j ?

Comment: @alexanoid No, regex don't use the index, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744303/how-to-search-with-cypher-2-0-case-insensitive