# How do a general search across string properties in my nodes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, neo4j.rb

Working with Neo4j in a Rails app.

I have nodes with several string properties containing long strings of user generated content.  For example in my nodes of type: "Book", I might have properties, "review", and "summary", which would contain long-form string values.

I was trying to design queries that returned nodes which match those properties to general language search terms provided by a user in a search box.  As my query got increasingly complicated, it occurred to me that I was trying to resolve natural language search.

I looked into some of the popular search gems in Rails, but they all seem to depend on ActiveRecord.  What search solutions exist for Neo4j.rb?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways that you could go about this!

As FrobberOfBits said, Neo4j has what are called "legacy indexes" which use Lucene it the background to provide indexing of generic things.  It does support the new schema indexes.  Unfortunately those are based on exact matches (though I'm pretty sure that will change in Neo4j 2.3.x somewhat).

Neo4j does support pattern matching on strings via the `=~` operator, but those queries aren't indexed.  So the performance depends on the size of your database.

We often recommend a gem called `searchkick` which lets you define indexes for Elasticsearch in your models.  Then you can just call a `Model.search` method to do your searches and it will first query elasticsearch to get the node IDs and then load those nodes via Neo4j.rb.  You can use that via the `neo4j-searchkick` gem: https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-searchkick

Lastly, if you're doing NLP and are trying to extract important words from your text, you could create a `Tag`/`Word` label and create relationships from your nodes to these NLP extracted nodes so that you can search based on those nodes in the future.  You could even build recommendations from one text node to another based on the number/type of common tag nodes.

Comment: If you have more questions feel free to ask on the Neo4j public slack group too: http://neo4j.com/blog/public-neo4j-users-slack-group/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anything specific exists for neo4j.rb and activerecord.  What I can say is that generally this stuff is handled through the use of [legacy indexes that are implemented by Lucene](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-lucene-extras.html).

The premise is that you create a lucene-managed index on certain properties, and that then gives you access to use the Lucene query language via cypher to get data from those indices.   Relative to neo4j.rb, [it doesn't look any different than running cypher queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360489/passing-a-lucene-query-to-neo4j-rest-api-using-cypher-2-0), like this:

```
START item=node:node_auto_index("(title:'foo bar' AND body:baz*) OR title:'bat'")
RETURN item
```

Note that lucene indexes and that query language can only be used in a `START` block, not a `MATCH` block.   Refer to the [Lucene Query Syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) to discover more about what you can do with that query syntax (fuzzy matching, wildcards, etc -- quite a bit more extensive than what regex would give you).

Comment: Unfortunately neo4j.rb doesn't support the legacy indexes ;(  We generally recommend searchkick to use elasticsearch